# html/js text input field with drop-down option

Tags: javascript, html, select, jquery-select2

I would like to have a text-input field that also has an optional drop-down. The ideal ui would look like a text input on default and accept text but when you click an arrow, a drop-down will show. It would also be nice to have the drop-down be implemented with select2 to allow easy searching of values (and that's what I've tried already).

My first attempt used the tagging feature in select2 but it's not exactly what I want as the user will type and then have to select their new input. The default is also not a text-input in this case. Thanks for any help. Also the options can't be hard-coded as we're polling a db for the items that the list would show.

updates:
An example would be something similar to this: jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger... where the default is an input text field and we have a button to select the date, but in this case, it's a button which would overlay a drop-down on the text-field.

I also looked at datalist and that would work but I don't think you can not hard-code the options.

Something like this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox .. would be perfect. But changes would be that it has to accept any entered option rather than reject it and also grab from a list instead. I'm not too familiar with front-end stuff, so if this is possible to do, can you let me know how and the basic idea? I don't think the list can be populated with something like a http get request?

Comment: use html and css to build a drop down  than javascript

Comment: But I'd like the default to look like a text box not a drop-down. And ideally use the existing drop-down I have made using select2 so I don't have to write searching. An example would be something similar to this: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger... where the default is an input text field and we have a button to select the date, but in this case, it's a button which would overlay a drop-down on the text-field.

Answer (score 0):

try using datalist html tag:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I found this in some other posts. It looks like it's not well supported by all browsers yet. I'm not sure if the datalist can be populated and not be hard-coded like that (drop-down list items are from polling a db).

Comment: Datalist is supported by all modern browsers(Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera, Mozilla Firefox) except Safari and it can be populated as well using loops.